# Make plots for selected rows and clinical parameters

Tags: shiny

I am trying to set up a shiny where I want to make boxplot for the values in data and have a dropdown for the "Gene" and clinical parameter (colnames in clinical). In this example the clinical dropdown will be `TumorLoad` and `Stage` and additional dropdown for `Gene1-6`

I have tried breifly, but this is probably wrong approach:

```
library(shiny)



ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("variable", "Clinical",choices = names(clinical)),
  plotOutput("myplot"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(data.m.plot,aes(input$variable,value,fill=input$variable)) + geom_boxplot()
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

data:

```
clinical <- data.frame(ID=c("Patient1","Patient2","Patient3","Patient4","Patient5","Patient6"),TumorLoad=c("High","High","High","Low","Low","Low"),Stage=c("1","1","1","3","3","3"))


data <- structure(list(Gene = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Gene1", "Gene2", 
"Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", "Gene6"), class = "factor"), Patient1 = c(24, 
42, 42, 4, 24, 24), Patient2 = c(23, 342, 4232, 4, 214, 244), 
    Patient3 = c(24, 432, 4232, 4, 244, 214), Patient4 = c(424, 
    142, 412, 4, 234, 214), Patient5 = c(24, 432, 423, 24, 24, 
    24), Patient6 = c(24, 432, 412, 4, 23, 241)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

plot script:

```
data.selected <- data[grep("Gene1",data$Gene),] #Dropdown menu for $Gene
data.m <- melt(data.selected,id.vars=("Gene"))
data.m.plot <- cbind(clinical,data.m) 
ggplot(data.m.plot,aes(data.m.plot$TumorLoad,value,fill=data.m.plot$TumorLoad)) + geom_boxplot() #Dropdown menu for clinical, in this example $TumorLoad is plotted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved like so:

1. Instead of melting and joining the data inside the app I do all data wrangling outside of the app.
2. Add a second selectintput
3. Plot using ggplot where I make use of aes_string to simply use the character inputs.

Try this:

```
clinical <- data.frame(ID=c("Patient1","Patient2","Patient3","Patient4","Patient5","Patient6"),TumorLoad=c("High","High","High","Low","Low","Low"),Stage=c("1","1","1","3","3","3"))


data <- structure(list(Gene = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Gene1", "Gene2", 
                                                        "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", "Gene6"), class = "factor"), Patient1 = c(24, 
                                                                                                                             42, 42, 4, 24, 24), Patient2 = c(23, 342, 4232, 4, 214, 244), 
                       Patient3 = c(24, 432, 4232, 4, 244, 214), Patient4 = c(424, 
                                                                              142, 412, 4, 234, 214), Patient5 = c(24, 432, 423, 24, 24, 
                                                                                                                   24), Patient6 = c(24, 432, 412, 4, 23, 241)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     -6L))


library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Prepare dataset. Make long (melt) and join
data_prep <- data %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Gene, names_to = "ID") %>% 
  left_join(clinical)


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("p", "Clinical p", choices = c("TumorLoad", "Stage")),
  selectInput("gene", "Gene", choices = unique(data_prep$Gene)),
  plotOutput("myplot"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # filter data by Gene
  data_selected <- reactive({
    filter(data_prep, Gene %in% input$gene)
  })
  
  # Plot. use aes_string to simply use character input p
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data_selected(), aes_string(input$p, "value", fill = input$p)) + 
      geom_boxplot()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```